# Multiple Google Sheet queries break when one of them returns "no data"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem where if one QUERY statement (in a group of multiple) return "no data", it breaks the entire formula. Here is a quick video showing this in action:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pud4zmjqopdqim5/shopping-list-explanation.mov

I have tried to wrap each query with IFERROR, for example:

```
IFERROR(QUERY('Step 2 - Snacks'!E:H, "select E,F where G = 'M' AND F > 0 AND H = 'Y'",0),0)
```

..but I still have the same issue.

I would like a solution where if any QUERY returns no data, then it is just ignored, but after a bunch of hours I am nearing the end of my tether and would appreciate some tips.

Update: [Here is the Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16jz6-ITvypbwGETB_zU7TiD6WxKmUuFsEAeyqdZumhM/edit?usp=sharing) (shared with anyone who has the link)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but where the query returns an error, try to place empty values for every column in the query.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Step 2 - Snacks'!E:H, "select E,F where G = 'M' AND F > 0 AND H = 'Y'",0),{"", ""})
```

Then, when you have multipled queries stacked, wrap an 'outer' query around everything filtering out the empty rows. Something like:

```
=QUERY( IFERROR(QUERY('Step 2 - Snacks'!E:H, "select E,F where G = 'M' AND F > 0 AND H = 'Y'",0),{"", ""}); IFERROR(QUERY(....), {"", ""}), "where Col1 <> ''")
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: This worked perfectly, with the second outer query removing the empty rows. Thanks so much, flagged as answered :)